# Can someone help me with making a while loop so I can keep putting in cin values after each calculation?

Tags: c++, while-loop

Can someone help me with making a while loop so I can keep putting in cin values after each calculation? here is my program. I am just tryin to make a while loop to keep the program running but I am not sure what condition I should put for while.

```
//This program calculates the roots of a quadratic equation.

#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

double a, b, c, root1, root2, disc, imaginarypart, realpart;
ofstream output ("E:result5.dat");  
cout<< " This program calculates the roots of a quadratic equation. ";
cout << " ax^2 + bx + c = 0\n\n";


cout << "enter values for a, b, and c.";
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
cin >> c;
disc = (pow(b,2) -4*a*c);

if ( a == 0.0 && b == 0.0)
cout << "the equation has no real roots.";
else if ( a == 0.0 )
cout << " The equation is linear and has a single root x = " << -c/b <<endl;


else 
{

if (disc > 0.0 )
{

    root1 = (-b +sqrt((b*b) -4*a*c))/2*a; 
    root2 = (-b -sqrt((b*b) -4*a*c))/2*a;
    cout << "The too roots are real and are X1 = " << root1 << " and X2 = " << root2 << endl;
}

else if (disc == 0.0)
{
cout<< "both roots are the same and are equal to " << -b/(2*a) << endl;
}

else
{
    realpart = -b/(2*a);
    imaginarypart = sqrt(-disc)/(2*a);
    cout << " The roots are imaginary = " << endl;
    cout << "x1 =" << realpart << "+" << imaginarypart << "i" << endl;
    cout << "x2 =" << realpart << "-" << imaginarypart << "i" << endl;
}


system ("pause");
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: while(1) help to solve this

Comment: break when you hit the end of input

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```cpp
std::string aAsString;
while(true)
{
    cout << "enter values for a, b, and c.; enter exit for quitting program";
    std::cin >> aAsString;
    if (aAsString == "exit")
        break;

    a = atof(aAsString.c_str());

    // remainder of your code...
}
```